# PHP Performance: Query to database on each hit?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, yii

I have a table EVENTS in a database. (MySQL)
When user GETs URL www.example.com/today server executes the PHP statements with SQL query to the database.

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE DATE(date_end) >= DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(date_start) <= DATE(NOW())
```

**Question: Is it worth to make it in this way whereas I could have made some 'prepared' static file or table with fresh events and its data every day?**

And additional question: Would you suggest to use Yii? Because it seems kinda slow on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Yii supports [caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) (I've personally never used Yii as i'm a symfony man, but this is irrelevant)

You can set the expiration of a cached file to, let's say 6 hours. After 6 hours, when a user requests the page, your page will be updated with the events from the database.

1 query per page request is really nothing, and even though you'll get a slight performance gain by using caching, it's really not worth the effort in implementing just for 1 query.

I have a site which on some pages has to execute up to 200+ queries. I have the pages cached so that the database is only called every few minutes to make sure that I'm not executing the same queries on every single page load. i.e. after 5 minutes, when the user makes a request, the cache file has expired and then new content is loaded from the db.

You can do optimisations. For example, take a look at YSlow. Using this firefox plugin you can look at where the bottle necks on your page are. i.e. many background images? convert it into a sprite. Not using a CDN for loading Jquery? then use a CDN. Resizing images using the width and height properties? Actually resize the image etc.

In terms of PHP performance. Take a look at [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) which is a PHP accelerator. You should notice a significant performance gain when your PHP app becomes complex and you're executing a lot of code. However, for a simple page calling just one query then you probably won't notice much of a performance gain.

For mysql, take advantage of indexes. If you're searching for an event using the events name column, make sure you have an index on this column.

For frameworks, you can use what you want. They can all be optimised to run quickly. The choice is yours.

So just to summarise:

For what you're doing. If it's just one query on a page, then there is not much point in using caching and a framework. If indeed your application becomes complex and you start using lots of queries then it would be beneficial to use a framework(separation of code, ORM, routing, form validation etc.) and take advantage of the caching capabilities that the framework has to offer.

Comment: Is good you do caching for pages that execute 200+ queries. But this is not the cure. You should identify why it need to execute 200+ queries. PS:- blindly expire the cache (every 5 minute) is not a wise move. The first user hit the page (after the 5 minute interval) will get a very bad response. And if there is more than one concurrent user accessing the same page, due to the cache is not in place, they will competing each other by execute all over the queries again.

Comment: @ajreal And how exactly would I optimise it when I have 80-100 tables? I need to have that many queries. And no, the page in question is cached for each individual user. i.e. they have their own cached version. Please do not make assumptions. Some complex web apps need that many queries.

Comment: Really? So how are you able to input any suggestions when you have no idea of the data structure of the database or indeed the nature of the SQL queries? 200 queries is not that much. Many complex web apps use far more than that (think of web apps with many widgets). Furthermore, the page load time is incredibly quick due to other optimisations. All of the queries have been analysed and in many cases, they have been re-written. The OP was asking whether use the YII framework and about the performance hit from using 1 query on 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use NOW() in your query.
NOW() is not cacheable into mysql query cache.

docs:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html

> A query cannot be cached if it contains any of the functions shown in the following table.
>   NOW()

Always use constant in your left-hand-side comparison.
In your case, you do a type cast from datetime (or timestamp) to date,
which is a bad habbit, consider this :-

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', time());
$end_date = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', time());

DATE(date_end) >= DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(date_start) <= DATE(NOW())
==>
date_end between $start_date and $end_date
and
date_start <= $end_date
```

More importantly, build an composite index on date_start, and date_end
if where clause always require comparison of both columns

Store everything in static is fine,
but it require more efforts to expire / invalidate the cache when there is an update.

Whether to use Yii is secondary consideration, fix the obvious problem first
(which is the expensive mysql query).